# internet access to VMs va vsphere ESXI 6

Tags: vmware

I installed Vsphere 6.0 on a VM workstation 11 and on booting it gave me an IP address (static) - 192.168.254.XX and i used the same address to log into the Vsphere Client.
In Vsphere Client, I created 01 VM. My ESXI machine in workstation is connected to physical NIC (Bridges connection) and is supposedly getting internet access.
How will the internet connection be routed to Vsphere VMs via ESXI system on VM Workstation. As per my understanding, the Vsphere client where my VMs are installed, is interfaced to ESXI system. So, do i need to NAT my NIC to the ESXI IP address or to my ISP address (DHCP)??

i want to give internet access to my VMs in Vsphere client How should i go about it? My internet connection is a DHCP based system.

Also, how to go about configuring DD-WRT to distribute internet to various VMs??

Regards
Ravs

Comment: This question should be asked on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you create two virtual manchine, you should create a virtual NIC for each, with different IP addresses. So you end up having 3 IP: ESXI native IP, VM1 IP as VM2 IP. If you want to access your VM from outside your lan, you should open the port on your router and then NAT to desired VM IP. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thanx Eric for a quick reply.  I am a little confused about the setup now. I have installed ESXi on VMware workstation and then used Vsphere client to log into it and create another VM in Vsphere client....How will the traffic flow now--Physical NIC to VMworkstation(ESXI) to VSphere Client(VM)?       If this is the case, then i have to NAT on VM too to connect to ESXI and then Bridge on ESXI to access physical NIC??

Comment: Let's see if i undestand correctly. Your operation system on the physical machine is ESXI rigth?, You give it a fixed IP and then connect to it with VSphere Client. One connected you créate a VM with its own operation system and its own IP, Now if you want to connect to your ESXI server with VSphere from outside you lan, you need open the VSphere port and forward to ESXI IP. If what you want to connect to the VM Operation system (for instance to use remote desktop) you need to open the necesary ports and forward it to VM IP. Is this what you are asking?